# the time in DateTimeField is not correct

Tags: python, django, django-models

Hello I am creating a website and trying to save the clock in time to the database every time a person clicks the clock in button but the time saved in the database is off by 8 hours. How do I fix this?

code where I use the DateTimeField:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime, date

#Create your models here.


class Name(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    timeIn = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: The time stored in the database is in UTC. So the time is off by 8 hours because you are present in a timezone that is offset by 8 hours from UTC

Comment: I am living in Malaysia so do I set TIME_ZONE ='Malaysia'?

Comment: As long as you have set `USE_L10N = True` in the settings Django will try to automatically localize any date / time values you render in a template. See [Format localization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/formatting/). This setting is set by default if the project is made using ` django-admin startproject` so most likely you **don't** need to do anything. As for the time being in UTC in the database? Let it be that way, you will display time to the users according to their locale anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try using django's in built timezone module:

```
from django.utils import timezone

class MyModel(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

This should use your computer's timezone and it should not be off by 8 hours anymore.

Comment: It gave me this warning:
(fields.E160) The options auto_now, auto_now_add, and default are mutually exclusive. Only one of these options may be present.

WARNINGS:
main.Name.timeIn: (fields.W161) Fixed default value provided.
        HINT: It seems you set a fixed date / time / datetime value as default for this field. This may not be what you want. If you want to have the current date as default, use `django.utils.timezone.now`

Comment: Try removing your other arguments `auto_not_add, etc` you should only need `default=timezone.now`

Comment: it still is off  by 8 hours

Comment: What are your USE_TZ and TIME_ZONE settings?

Comment: @TimNyborg I did not set those

Answer (score 0):

When you have timezone `USE_TZ` as `True` in your `settings.py` file, then the datetime would look something like this - `2021-04-06 12:35:19.646177+04` in the DB.

It will not create any problem when you access it, you can get the correct timezone aware datetime like this -

```
from django.utils.timezone import localtime

name = Name.objects.get(pk=1)
t = localtime(name.timeIn)
```

`t` here will give the correct datetime according to your timezone.

Comment: may I ask what is pk?

Comment: `pk` is primary key. You can query with `id` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where my timezone was off by 5 hours,
all I did was set the `USE_TZ` to `False` and added another variable with the name of `USE_I18N` and set it to `True`.
I read it on this page of [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#std-setting-USE_L10N) that the former variable, i.e. `USE_I18N` somehow sets the time zone to the local computers timezone.
I am a new learner as well. So, it would be great if some one explains whether it's a good idea to use `USE_I18N` or not.